# Confusion about the verb 'welcome'`

Tags: verbs

While learning the position of the adverbs in a sentence, I came across this sentence.

> I am obviously not **welcome** here.

I'm **not** asking about the adverb *obviously's* position here, but in this sentence, the word *welcome* refers to *verb*, does not it?

It should go like this -

> I am obviously not **welcomed** here [maybe, because I'm not invited].

Comment: It is simply an adjective, not a verb in this case. "You are welcome" is grammatically not different from "You are blue".

Comment: @oerkelens then what about I welcome you here. And if that's correct, what about its past tense? *Don't forget. She is always special to me. I'll treat her the same way as I welcomed her last year.*

Comment: @oerkelens *You are welcome* is different than *I welcome you* also, *you should welcome others* or *I welcome your proposals.* clearly, that's verb, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, in those sentences it is a verb. "Welcome" can be a verb, an adjective or a noun.

Comment: @oerkelens So *you are not welcomed or welcome?*

Comment: Can be both :) I put it in an answer with some more detail :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Welcome" can be a verb, and is then used accordingly:

> I welcome you to my house.
>   I will always welcome her.
>   He welcomed me to his party.

But it can also be an adjective:

> You are welcome in my house.
>   She is always welcome.
>   I was welcome at his party.
>   She made me feel welcome.
>   The break was a welcome relief from the hard work.

It can even be a noun:

> I gave him a very warm welcome to my house.

Sometimes, you can use similar but slightly different constructions, but the meaning of your sentence will change:

> I was welcome at his party.
>   I was welcomed at his party.

The first simply means that I was invited, or at least, my presence was appreciated, at his party.
The second version indicates that someone actually bade me welcome when I arrived at the party.

To include the examples from the OP:

> I am obviously not welcome here.

My presence here is obviously not appreciated. Whatever the reason, people would be happier if I did would not be here or come here.

> I am obviously not welcomed here.

I might as such be welcome here, I might have an invitation to this party, but as you can see, obviously nobody is standing at the door to welcome me. 
(I guess I'll just sneak in and get a beer.)

Comment: that means if I say in my original example , *I'm not welcomed here.* - that's not incorrect...right?

Comment: It is not incorrect, but it means something different from "_I'm not welcome here_". I edited my answer to include your examples :)

Comment: @Maulik: Although your *I'm not welcomed here* version is theoretically possible (i.e. - there's no clear grammatical principle by which it can be adjudged "incorrect") in practice it's almost impossible to imagine a native speaker saying it. Even oerkelens's brave attempt to provide a credible illustrative context in his edit doesn't really work - when describing his circumstances *at the doorway*, a "non-greeted" guest would almost certainly phrase it as *"I am not being welcomed"*. But these are really all academic points - only *"I am not welcome"* is actually relevant to your context.

Comment: "When I go to the Burger Place, there is always a greeter in the door saying "hi." By contrast, when I go to the Pizza Place, I'm not welcomed." (But this is a huge stretch, and the listener might mishear it as "I'm not welcome" which has a negative connotation.)

Comment: @hunter: Like I say, these are academic points. Although oerkelens has given a comprehensive (and "not incorrect") answer here, the net result is that OP posted a comment showing that he *still* assumed *"I'm not welcomed here"* is "not incorrect". Arguably at that point he was actually *less* well-informed than when he first posted the question. At least *then* he might have been prepared to accept the answer "No, that is incorrect" (which in practice is all even a native speaker normally needs to know for such contexts).

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry sorry, I know :-) OP, in case it's still not clear: it's technically possible but extremely hard to think of a useful meaning of "I'm not welcomed here" whereas "I'm not welcome here" is a common expression

Comment: @hunter: np (good comment, btw). I think there's not universal agreement on the underlying principles which should govern answers on ELL - not unreasonably, some learners resent the idea that they should only be told about *the most common usages*, for example. And I see that you yourself are not very active on ELU - where I think it's entirely appropriate to explore the *margins* of acceptable usage (since that should *not* be a site for teaching people "the basics"). Hopefully the "right level" for ELL will become clearer over time (oerkelens - I intend no criticism of your answer as such!).

Comment: I actually took your remark as a compliment. I elaborated my answer a bit more than I would usually have done based on who asked the question and the discussion that started in the comments :)